# В чём заключается ошибка когда запускаю rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
   e:\Programm\RuHealer\RuHealer>rails server
E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/
  app_loader.rb:40:in `exec': No such file or directory - "E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe" (Errno::ENOENT)
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40:in `block in exec_app'
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:35:in `loop'
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:35:in `exec_app'
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rails:22:in `load'
        from E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'код
```

Comment: Запускать руби на винде - это всегда больно. Очень рекомендую поставить линукс второй осью и поднять всё на нём, а не пытаться решить эту и все последующие ошибки. Либо воспользоваться облачной IDE, если вы просто хотите попробовать руби

Comment: В любом случае, было бы здорово отформатировать вопрос так, чтобы его было удобно читать, а также добавить чуть больше деталей о том, как вы устанавливали руби и рельсы

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, проблема заключается в пробелах в пути "Ruby on Rails" - пробел не является допустимым символом, поэтому bash пожаловался на "E:/Programm/Ruby on rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe"

Можете попробовать это решение: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545361/rails-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)